# How to reload /etc/environment from shell script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, environment-variables, sh

So I have this shell script that checks and then concats an environmental variable to /etc/environment, then reloads the file without having to logout/login:

```
#!/bin/sh
portvar="PORT=5000"
echo $portvar
grep -q $portvar /etc/environment && echo "EV already in" || echo $portvar >> /etc/environment
set -a; source /etc/environment; set +a;
```

When I run it, I get the error `./test.sh: 5: ./test.sh: source: not found`. However, if I run `set -a; source /etc/environment; set +a;` directly in the terminal it updates the environmental variable just fine. I have no idea what the `set` command does, I just found it in another stack overflow question.

Any idea why it runs in the terminal directly but not in the .sh file?
Thanks

Comment: This works for me in windows either as is or with dot instead of source. can you try running it as sh your_script.sh? on which os are you running it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/bin/sh` on your system is likely some shell that isn't bash and doesn't implement the `source` command.  On my Ubuntu 20.04 system `/bin/sh` is actually [dash](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dash).

The `source` command is not defined by POSIX as part of the [shell command language](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html) nor is it one of the required [special built-in utilities](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/idx/sbi.html).  It's a non-standard feature provided by `bash`.  However, [the `.` command](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/dot.html), which does the same thing, is specified by POSIX.

So you can use `.` instead, e.g. `. /etc/environment`.  Or if you want to keep using `source`, then you need to have your script run by bash or some other shell that supports it, by changing the shebang line to `#!/bin/bash`.

There is a tool called [checkbashisms](https://linux.die.net/man/1/checkbashisms) that can help you find unintentional uses of bash-specific features in your scripts.  When run on your script, it flags this:

```
possible bashism in foo.sh line 5 (should be '.', not 'source'):
```

Comment: Perfect. Used `.`

Comment: @hamncheez:- How you resolved this? does the last line should be  
set -a; . /etc/environment; set +a;  i.e. '.' instead of 'source' ? bcause . /etc/environment is not working for me ?